# Issue with bulk emails not sending

Tags: email, iis-7, iis-6, asp.net

We've moved one of our clients' sites that was on a server running IIS6 to a server running IIS7. They fairly regularly send out bulk emails - roughly 5000 - with no problems.

Now that the site has been moved to the new server, none of the emails seem to be sending, although the actual code for sending the emails hasn't changed.

I don't really know very much about IIS but I was wondering if anyone could tell me if IIS7 deals with bulk emails in a different way to IIS6? Or if there is something else that it might be.

Also, why would none of the emails be sending if this is the issue? Wouldn't at least some get sent out?

Answer (score 1):

Did the old server use the SMTP service in IIS6?  If so, is the SMTP service configured on the new server?  I don't think it is active by default in IIS 7.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We also have several other of our clients' websites on the new server, two of which are a duplication of the site that we are having problems with. Those two other sites have also had bulk emails sent out, but only 2 or 3 thousand, rather than 5000. They sent out fine. So I am assuming that the SMTP service is configured on the new server, or all sites wouldn't send emails?

Comment: Also, in the older server it used smartermail's servers and this is still the case on the new server.